# Lambda@Edge Set Cookie on Origin Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cloudfront, setcookie, aws-lambda-edge

Im doing a test A/B for 2 websites, I have a static React site on s3 and a site on Hostgator.

I want to decide when an user go to **site A** and **site B** and store the site decided within a **cookie**. But the problem is that **the cookie is not getting set when the request is fowarded**.

Here's the following code, this lambda is triggered by CloudFront on **Origin Request**:

```html
function getHeader(name, headers){
    let result = null;
    Object.keys(headers).forEach((key) => {
        if (key.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase() && headers[key].length)
            result = headers[key];
    });
    return result;
}

function randomChoose() {
    if (Math.random() >= .7) {
        return 'new-site';
    }

    return 'old-site';
}

function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  const cookies = getHeader('cookie', headers);
  
  let choosenAB;
  let setCookie;
  let cookieA = 'controlversion=new-site';
  let siteA = 'new-site-example.com';
  let cookieB = 'controlversion=old-site';
  let siteB = 'old-site-example.com';
  
  if (cookies && Array.isArray(cookies)) {
      cookies.forEach(val => {
          if (val.value.indexOf(cookieA))
              choosenAB = 'new-site';
          else if (val.value.indexOf(cookieB))
              choosenAB = 'old-site';
      });
  } 
    
  if (!choosenAB) {
      const expireDate = addMinutes(new Date(), 5);
      choosenAB = randomChoose();
      setCookie = `controlversion=${choosenAB}; expires=${expireDate.toGMTString()}; Secure; HttpOnly`;
  }
  
  let origin = request.origin.s3;
  if (choosenAB === 'old-site')
  {
      request.origin = {
          custom: {
              domainName: siteB,
              port: 80,
              protocol: 'http',
              readTimeout: 20,
              keepaliveTimeout: 5,
              customHeaders: {},
              headers: {},
              sslProtocols: ['TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1'],
          }
      }
      if (request.uri && request.uri.indexOf('index.html'))
          request.uri = request.uri.replace('index.html', '');
      origin = request.origin.custom;
      request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: siteB }];
  }
  if (setCookie) {
      if (!origin.customHeaders)
          origin.customHeaders = {};
      origin.customHeaders['set-cookie'] = [];
      origin.customHeaders['set-cookie'].push({ key: 'Set-Cookie', value: setCookie });
  }

  callback(null, request);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.